# React ES6 SystemJS - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected token <(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I have `react` and `react-dom` installed and imported in via the `System.config` below, but I still get this error below:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error:  Unexpected token <(…)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ES2015 Module Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="lib/system.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            "baseURL": "src",

            // Set defaultJSExtensions to true so you don't have to use .js extension when importing the es6 module.
            "defaultJSExtensions": true,

            // 'plugin-babel' or 'traceur' or 'typescript'
            transpiler: 'traceur',

            map: {
                'react': './node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js',
                'react-dom': './node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js',
                'traceur': './lib/traceur.min.js',
                'plugin-babel': './lib/plugin-babel/plugin-babel.js',
                'systemjs-babel-build': './lib/plugin-babel/systemjs-babel-browser.js'
            },
        });
        System.import("app.js");
    </script>
</body>
<div id="example"></div>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Any ideas what else do I have to configure?

Comment: Does your traceur transpiler support jsx out of the box? You might be missing a preset for react.

Comment: @Wex `Does your traceur transpiler support jsx out of the box?` probably not. how do i configure traceur  to support it?

Comment: I couldn't find any evidence that traceur is capable of doing that. Try babel instead.

Comment: @TamasHegedus i am now trying to use babel. but how to configure it with systemjs? the babel documentation is really poor written and annoying!

Comment: @TamasHegedus that is for expressjs apps. i am not developing an express app.

Comment: https://github.com/lalitkapoor/systemjs-es6-react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json that is nothing about babel!

Comment: @teelou Lol sry, it had a promising name

Comment: I am starting to think that SystemJS doesn't support jsx

Comment: maybe this one can help http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/installing-the-jsx-babel-plugin.html

Comment: @TamasHegedus found my solution - browserify. see my answer below! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browserify is the best solution (for production & development) - to me:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('build', function() {
    // app.js is your main JS file with all your module inclusions
    return browserify({entries: 'src/app.js', debug: true})
        .transform("babelify", { presets: ["es2015", "react"] })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('compile.min.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

As for non-production with SystemJS (painfully slow):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.19.js"></script>
<script>
System.config({
  transpiler: 'babel',
  babelOptions: {}
});
System.import('./main.js');
</script>
```

You still can use gulp for development. Just add this to the gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function () {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

This saves you from other tedious dev workflows as [listed](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/taming-react-setup/) here.

Answer (score -1):

`Unexpected token <` usually occurs in html5 applications, when the server is configured to return the contents of `index.html` instead of 404 pages (so pressing f5 on dynamic routing still works). Check then network panel in your browsers developer console, and see which js file was served with html contents.

Comment: it is this `app.js` for reactjs.